# switched outlets stopped working

Tags: electrical

All the switched outlets in my living room stopped working.  The non switched outlets work fine.  There is only one breaker for the living room.   Where do I begin to figure out what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Comment: Start at the switch. Determine if there's power to the switch, and power through the switch when it's on. Then move forward or backward through the circuit, depending on what you find at the switch.

Comment: You sound like a beginner at electrical work, If not, apologies.  Be very careful in tracing the fault, because you can get a nasty shock if you find the live wire the "wrong way."  Use a voltmeter and be sure to keep your hands away from any wires or binding posts you are testing.

Comment: I found a bad switch, replaced it and all works fine.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Mike: You could post that as an answer.